# Can languages merge together?

Tags: historical-linguistics

This problem's going through my head for a while. Take Indonesia - everybody speaks fluently Indonesian there but Indonesian remains a second, "official language" for most people anyway. In Canada, there's​ a huge percentage of bilinguals - but even though French and English affect each other and create neologisms occasionally, they seem to remain two very distinct communication systems (I have no references for this).

Though, do languages merge together or tend to merge together when coexisting in an area for certain time?

Comment: Anglo-Saxon and Norman French merged together and as a result Middle English appeared.

Comment: Related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/989/is-there-any-case-of-a-convergent-language-family

Comment: There are contact languages and "mixed languages' like [Michif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michif_language), which is a blend of French and Cree. You could call it merging if you want. But languages like Michif are very rare.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'merge together'. Have a read of WP on [language strata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratum_(linguistics)). This is a more common situation than the "mixed language" mentioned by jlawler.

Comment: Sally Thomason's book _Language Contact_ has a good overview of the various possibilities, and lots of interesting examples.

Answer (score 1):

No. History knows no equal merge. If two languages are merging, usually it means one of them is heavily influenced by the other.

Comment: Some varieties of [surzhyk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surzhyk) have practically equal proportion of features from both languages. Have you heard surzhyk?

Comment: @Yellow Sky this may be just because there is still existing dialect continuum between the languages. I do not know Surzhyk but if it is not the case, information in the Internet mostly indicates it is Ukrainian-based language with a lot of Russian vocabulary.

Comment: It's definitely not a dialect within that continuum, and there are really many variants of surzhyk, some of them are like the one you described, but some are like Russian with half of words and half of grammar forms being Ukrainian.

Answer (score 0):

According to some, [yes](http://lsa2013.lsa.umich.edu/2012/05/bilingual-mixed-languages/#). I was in the class provided in the link. The example I remember the most was this language somewhere in eastern Russia where all the nouns came from one language and all the verbs from the other (the two languages being a native language and Russian).